# AngularJS ng-options error: Can't copy! Making copies of Window or Scope instances is not supported

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ng-options

I'm using AngularJS version 1.5.11.

I have created a select (multiple) element using ng-options:

```
<select multiple class="form-control" ng-model="vm.selectedBuildings" ng-options="building as building.name for building in vm.buildings track by building.id"></select>
```

Whenever I select one of the elements, instead of the element being pushed to the selectedBuildings array, I get the error: "Can't copy! Making copies of Window or Scope instances is not supported."

I have spent countless hours trying to figure this out. Someone please help!

**Relevant code from the controller**

```
var self = this;
self.selectedBuildings = [];

function getBuildings() {
    buildingService.getBuildings(campusId, function (buildings) {
        // retrieve buildings from API
        self.buildings = buildings;

        // etc, etc
    });
}

// I am using a Bootstrap modal to display some information.
// I have multiple structures but only one modal, so when the
// modal is shown, I dynamically populate self.selectedBuildings.
$("#modal-lot").on("shown.bs.modal", function () {
    // etc, etc
    var lot = self.lots[self.structureToUpdate];

    for (var i = 0; i < self.buildings.length; i++) {
        let building = self.buildings[i];
        let index = lot.buildings.indexOf(building.id);
        if (index > -1) {
            self.selectedBuildings.push(building);
        }
    }
    // etc, etc

    $scope.$apply();
});

// When the modal is hidden, clear the array
$("#modal-lot").on("hidden.bs.modal", function () {
    self.selectedBuildings = [];
});
```

**The Error Message**

```
Error: [ng:cpws] Can't copy! Making copies of Window or Scope instances is not supported.
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.11/ng/cpws
http://***/static/bower_components/angular/angular.js:68:32
copyElement@http://***/static/bower_components/angular/angular.js:961:21
copyRecurse@http://***/static/bower_components/angular/angular.js:933:41
copyRecurse@http://***/static/bower_components/angular/angular.js:933:41
copyRecurse@http://***/static/bower_components/angular/angular.js:933:41
copyRecurse@http://***/static/bower_components/angular/angular.js:933:41
copyRecurse@http://***/static/bower_components/angular/angular.js:922:37
copyRecurse@http://***/static/bower_components/angular/angular.js:933:41
copyRecurse@http://***/static/bower_components/angular/angular.js:933:41
copyRecurse@http://***/static/bower_components/angular/angular.js:933:41
copyRecurse@http://***/static/bower_components/angular/angular.js:922:37
copyRecurse@http://***/static/bower_components/angular/angular.js:933:41
http://***/static/bower_components/angular/angular.js:29665:91
forEach@http://***/static/bower_components/angular/angular.js:325:24
readNgOptionsMultiple@http://***/static/bower_components/angular/angular.js:29663:18
http://***/static/bower_components/angular/angular.js:31995:57
$apply@http://***/static/bower_components/angular/angular.js:18094:30
http://***/static/bower_components/angular/angular.js:31994:21
dispatch@https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js:3:10320
```

Comment: Send more code from your controller

Comment: I don't think there's anything in the code you've shown us that would cause this error.

Comment: I just added some more code. Does this help at all?

Comment: Could you be having a circular reference in a model?

Answer (score 0):

try initializing self.selectedBuildings as array at the beginning of the controller as shown below

self.selectedBuildings = [];

Answer (score 0):

You should initialize `selectedBuildings` on the `$scope`, not on `this`.

```
$scope.selectedBuildings = [];
```